# How to make a full Ubuntu install with a LiveCD-like bootloader?

Tags: boot, usb, 15.10, uefi, live-cd

Interestingly, on my Surface Pro 3 a LiveCD installation of Ubuntu (15.10) would boot without any issues.

However, a full install on a USB3 SSD, (either in UEFI or non-UEFI mode) with or without Secure Boot would fail to load. I made the installations by installing them through Virtual Box and having the SSD exposed to the Guest OS (Ubuntu Installer Disk).

Does anyone know what the difference in the boot chain is for LiveCDs and full install? Can I get a full install with a LiveCD-like boot chain so that it would boot on my Surface Pro?

Comment: Must be something about GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader). You need to install GRUB in the root of your ssd (not to a particular partition). On startup you need to find a boot menu and choose that ssd as first boot device.

Comment: @ipselute did that... but thanks all the same

Comment: It seems that Microsoft (and Windows) is getting more and more stubborn with each device. It's just amazing to see how much time and effort they put into keeping linux out of their devices.

Comment: @chaskes Well, OP said that the answer there solved it, so…

Comment: @BharadwajRaju So it's a duplicate.

Comment: @chaskes OK, then.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the files on the UEFI partition. This answer did it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/740482/11397

Horay!

Comment: Please click the check bubble / accept answer as solution for question. There are currently 78,741 unanswered questions on this site. One less will keep the morale up.