# Add Grub 2 Boot Entry

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

been trying to boot ubuntu EFI mode installed on my internal HD with ubuntu 16.04 but nothing does it

If I boot without the USB stick I have a no bootable device error

I cannot figure how to add manually the entry in the grub bootloader using the "try ubuntu" boot.

Can please someone point me in the right direction where to find information on how to add a menuentry in the 40_custom file ? I tried various options on the internet but 2 days and no success :( What is the correct way of configuring Grub2 manually ?

I have an ACER aspire 11 if that is any use. I disabled secure boot already.

I booted from boot repair disk and here is my report: paste.ubuntu.com/23196933

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have tried to boot manually from the grub command line by entering:
grub> set root=(hd1,gpt1)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-31-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-31-generic
grub> boot

Comment: I booted from boot repair disk and here is my report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23196933

Comment: One more thing I noticed; when I install in a VM at some point during the install I am asked to update the grub booloader.
when I install on my laptop I am not asked that so is it a bug in the installer ?

Comment: It looks like your USB installer flash drive is promoted to sda and you are installing to a media card mmcblk0. But in UEFI mode grub only installs to drive seen as sda, so it may install the version of grub to boot install in the installer's ESP - efi system partition. But external drives only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Do you now have a /EFI/ubuntu folder in installer?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help; feels like we are going in the right direction as my EFI folder is empty :/ the media card is my internal memory of the laptop: 32gb. I think that is what they use on cheap laptop like mine; no real hd

Comment: Did you get a new /EFI/ubuntu folder in the installer? If not, you need to create a separate ESP on your installer, with boot flag. You probably will have to move the /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi to that partition to be able to boot installer. Then when you install Ubuntu or reinstall grub in UEFI mode it will write a new folder /EFI/ubuntu. You then should be able to copy /EFI/ubuntu from sda to sdb. You may need to copy again to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi as the fallback entry.http://askubuntu.com/questions/740290/installed-ubuntu-15-1-on-usb-full-install-but-it-wont-boot